# How to make a list of proportion tables relative to each row?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, row, proportions

I have this dataset and list of dataframe matrixes as follows :

```
set.seed(222)
df = data.frame(x = trunc(runif(10,0,2)),
                y = trunc(runif(10,4,6)),
                z = trunc(runif(10,19,21)),
                m = trunc(runif(10,28,30)))
df


t1 = table(df$x,df$y)
t2=table(df$z,df$m)


L = list(t1,t2)

L1 <- lapply(L, as.data.frame.matrix)
```

The output is

```
[[1]]
  4 5
0 4 2
1 3 1

[[2]]
   28 29
19  3  2
20  1  4
```

I wish to create proportion tables as for example for the first elements :

```
[[1]]
  4 5
0 4/(4+2) 2/(4+2)
1 3/(3+1) 1/(3+1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to iterate over elements in `L1`, obtain `rowSums` and get proportions.

```
  sapply(L1, function(x) {
  tmp <- x[1, ]
  tmp <- tmp/rowSums(tmp)
  tmp
})
 [,1]      [,2]
4 0.6666667 0.6 
5 0.3333333 0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `proportions`

```
 sapply(L1, \(x) proportions(as.matrix(x), 1)[1,])
       [,1] [,2]
4 0.6666667  0.6
5 0.3333333  0.4
```